# Filter list of Objects according to the month?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using graphs, so whenever I choose to show data according to the months, I will have to show data for the each month, I have fields like totalAmount, paidAmount , I should sum data for that month.

```
const myArray = [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "userId": null,
    "invoiceNumber": "biscuitInvoice",
    "billedBy": 1,
    "billedTo": 2,
    "addGst": false,
    "invoiceDate": "2021-05-08T12:05:00",
    "dueDate": "2021-05-21T12:03:00",
    "totalAmount": 11.8,
    "discountSymbol": null,
    "discountPercent": null,
    "subTotal": null,
    "notes": null,
    "signature": null,
    "reachMail": "",
    "reachPhoneNo": null,
    "businessLogo": null,
    "clientName": "Checking Business",
    "businessName": "Chocolate Business",
    "paymentAmount": 140,
    "status": "Created",
    "igst": 1.8,
    "cgst": 0,
    "amount": null,
    "sgst": 0,
    "businessClient": null,
    "businessProfile": null,
    "invoiceAttachments": [],
    "invoiceItems": [],
    "invoiceTerms": []
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "userId": null,
    "invoiceNumber": "invq32",
    "billedBy": 1,
    "billedTo": 3,
    "addGst": false,
    "invoiceDate": "2021-04-04T10:10:22",
    "dueDate": "2021-05-13T10:10:00",
    "totalAmount": 354,
    "discountSymbol": null,
    "discountPercent": null,
    "subTotal": null,
    "notes": null,
    "signature": null,
    "reachMail": "",
    "reachPhoneNo": null,
    "businessLogo": null,
    "clientName": "Checking",
    "businessName": "Chocolate Business",
    "paymentAmount": 120,
    "status": "Paid",
    "igst": 54,
    "cgst": 0,
    "amount": null,
    "sgst": 0,
    "businessClient": null,
    "businessProfile": null,
    "invoiceAttachments": [],
    "invoiceItems": [],
    "invoiceTerms": []
  }
]
```

In that list, I have invoiceDate, one object is of april month and other is of May month.

[Click here what I meant to do,I want this functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0eEP.png)

How can I do that, any help?

Comment: Do what? ... what exactly is the problem? Where is month? Is it based on dates?

Comment: yeah based on dates, according to invoiceDate in that objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function you need:

```js
function getDesiredMonth(data, month) {
    return data.filter((item) => item.invoiceDate.split("-")[1] === month)
}
```

For example, you can call it like this to get May invoices:
`getDesiredMonth(myArray, '05')`

Let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: Appreciate it if you accept my answer then

Answer (score 0):

Answering cause I dont have enough rep to comment.

I guess you can follow these steps:

1. Initialize aggregate variables that you need (basically sum of sgst or whatever) to 0.
2. Iterate over list
3. Use library such as luxon or moment to parse invoice date (they're in ISO, so it'll be straightforward)
4. Identify month number from parsed object.
5. Aggregate whatever data you need into the variables initiaziled earlier (eg. `total_sgst += current_obj.sgst`)
6. ???
7. Profit?

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterDataByMonth(data, month){
    return data.filter(i => new Date(i.invoiceDate).getMonth() + 1 === month);
}
```

Comment: Will try and let you know